# How can I remove slashes(\\) from the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this.

```
""\"\\\"\\\\\\\"<img title='In Progress' src='img/In Progress.ico' class='clsstatusimginner'/><span class='clstaskidlink' title='Explore about Master Setting in TP' onclick='taskLink(13721,89,Explore about Master Setting in TP)'>Explore about Master Setting in TP</span>\\\\\\\"\\\"\"""
```

I trying to extract the image tag from the string like following way.
How can I remove the extra slashes.

```
<img title='In Progress' src='img/In Progress.ico' class='clsstatusimginner'/><span class='clstaskidlink' title='Explore about Master Setting in TP' onclick='taskLink(13721,89,Explore about Master Setting in TP)'>Explore about Master Setting in TP</span>
```

I need to remove slashes("\") from the string, please can anyone help me.
Thanks.

**Update 1:** I got origin for this cause.
But I don't understand why this is happening.
Problem is:

```
 var vrTaskSubject= $("#lblTskSubject").text()
```

Above one giving the result like this:

```
""\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"<img title='Planned' src='img/Planned.ico' class='clsstatusimginner'/><span class='clstaskidlink' title='Format the Campus drive machine and set up the machine ready for campus' onclick='taskLink(14492,133,Format the Campus drive machine and set up the machine ready for campus,)'>Format the Campus drive machine and set up the machine ready for campus</span>\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\"""
```

Then As soon as this was stringified it was adding more slashes like this

```
 vrTskSubject = JSON.stringify($("#lblTskSubject").text());
```

This is giving the results like this.

```
""\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"<img title='Planned' src='img/Planned.ico' class='clsstatusimginner'/><span class='clstaskidlink' title='Format the Campus drive machine and set up the machine ready for campus' onclick='taskLink(14492,133,Format the Campus drive machine and set up the machine ready for campus,)'>Format the Campus drive machine and set up the machine ready for campus</span>\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\"""
```

Like this as many times the string is stringified that many slashes adding.
Please help me why stringify doing this. Is there reason behind this.
How can I fix this, Please need help

Comment: What is the origin of these extra slashes? I guess, this is what should be fixed

Comment: Right now I have no idea where it was that origin.
Anyway let me try to figure out that origin.
Then I will come back, but mean time if you have any solution please share with me

Comment: Can you please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

`myString.replace(/\\/g, "")`

A fully working example is :

```
var myString = "aa ///\\\\\\";
myString.replace(/\\/g, "")
// Outputs : "aa ///"
```

The `g` flag will remove every instances of **`\`** in your string. And we have to escape the pattern using **`\`** else you would get an error.

**EDIT 1 :** After seeing with OP in chat (you can see the full conversation in comments below), here is the solution for **HIS** specific issue :

First, remove noisy chars. in the string coming from the server

```
taskSubject = sourceGrid[0].TaskName.replace(/#%&%#/g, "");
```

Then remove the backslashes and extra quotes using

```
myString.replace(/\\|"/g, "")
```

Comment: / != \ not what looking for OP

Comment: Oh ! Sorry, it's fixed, too early in the morning for me, thanks for telling me.

Comment: Did you check that snippet, That not works for me @ MEGADEVOPS

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: That not working for my string which I added in  my question.
I think somewhere am doing something wrong

Comment: If possible can you try with my string

Comment: It is not working with your string because there is an invalid escape **\** in it. You should no even be trying to work with this but as @A.Wolff said find the origin of this "string" and fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122739/discussion-between-megadevops-and-kernal-lora).